# ExpressJS: expose Event Processing system as a REST Service API

Tags: rest, express, web-services, design-patterns, rabbitmq

I am looking for a way to expose an existing event processing system to the external world using a `REST interface`. I have existing system design where we have `RabbitMQ` message queues where a publisher could post a message and then wait for the message processed results on a separate queue. Message ID is used to track the output to the original message on the output queue.

[image: Proposed Design]

Now I want this to be exposed to the external consumers but we don't want to expose our `RabbitMQ` endpoint for this, so I was wondering if anyone has managed to achieve something similar to this using ExpressJS. Above diagram shows the current thought process

Main challenge I am facing here is that; some of this message processing could take more than couple of minutes, so was not sure how best to develop a API like this. Choices like should I create a polling interface for client here or is there a technology these days that help eliminate the polling on the client API to verify if the message is processed and get the result.

Can someone please help me with a good approach to manage these sort of requirement.

Comment: You can use https://rxjs.dev/guide/observable

Answer (score 0):

I finally ended up going the webhook way. Now when the REST API service receives a request, the client need to also provide a webhook and this will be registered with the client request and server will call it back when the results are available.